# Check for null value and still get a warning

Tags: c#, null

I can't understand why in this code I get a warning (CS8604) on the statement `value.ToString()` at the last line. It's often that i check for null value and still get a warning.

```
foreach (Cell c in cells)
{
    if (c.CellReference == null) continue;
    if (c.CellReference.Value == null) continue;
    var value = Excel.GetCellValue(c);  // Return type is 'Object?'
    if (value == null) continue;
    fieldNameAndIndex.Add(value.ToString(), c.CellReference.Value.ColumnIndex() ?? 1);
}
```

Thx in advance,

EDIT:
***Ok, Second version based on comments :***

```
foreach (Cell c in cells.Where(c => (c.CellReference != null) && (c.CellReference.Value != null) ))
{
    var value = Excel.GetCellValue(c);
    if (value == null || value.ToString() == null) continue;
    fieldNameAndIndex.Add(value.ToString(), c.CellReference.Value.ColumnIndex() ?? 1);
}
```

But now I have 2 warnings on both `value.ToString()` and `c.CellReference.Value` ... Is this a problem ? How to prevent those warnings ?

Comment: There's probably a bug in the CFA for `continue`. By the way, that code is awful. Use a `where` clause or a pattern.

Comment: Because `object.ToString()` returns `string?`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring.

Comment: You can replace the two ifs with one: `if (c.CellReference?.Value == null) continue;` and also `if (value?.ToString() == null) continue;`

Comment: After the question update, the issue still exists. `value.ToString()` may return null on the second invocation, even if it doesn't in the first. There are no guarantees that it is a pure function.

Comment: If the cell is supposed to contain a string, then you can simplify the code with pattern matching: `if (Excel.GetCellValue(c) is string value) { ... }`

Comment: If you were to do this: `if (value == null) continue; var str = value.ToString(); if (str == null) continue; fieldNameAndIndex.Add(str,` then there would be no CS8604 warning.

Comment: What is `Excel.GetCellValue`? Your own class? A library? Most libraries don't require cell-by-cell access. You can get the values of an entire range at once instead of iterating over cells. Excel itself works with ranges

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `value = value ?? string.Empty;` This and this-like assignments helped me a lot when importing/exporting to Excel.
The other thing, I try not to name vars by "value" name. On one hand they are descriptive, on the other hand, easy to confuse.